# Sending resistance values over bluetooth

Tags: microcontroller, wireless, resistance, bluetooth

I am diving into the deep here, as I am only familiar with audio electronics (guitar related). I thought of an educational project for myself to learn. It should be a miniature solution for the following (basic) problem:

**I want to read out the resistance of several potentiometers and send this value to my phone. The total size should be around 2 x 2 x 1 cm excluding battery.**

I think I will need the following:

- Bluetooth module 4.0
- Microcontroller to read out the potentiometer
- Battery (coin?)

Upon researching I was overwhelmed with the various chips available. When I thought I found a solution, it turned out it was obsolete and rather power hungry. 
So I am turning to this great community. Can anyone give me a pointer where to start looking? The cheaper and smaller the better. Programming a microcontroller is OK with me, can probably look that up somewhere as part of the learning process!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Instead of browsing for chips, look for a complete **module**. Some modules even have a simple microController on board. Probably that will not fit your small size needs but I would ignore that for the moment and deal with that later.

Comment: I would consider this very hard, mainly on the phone side. Unless there exists a phone app that can read readings from Bluetooth, you have to make the app yourself, which is a COMPLETE pain to learn. You could try two arduinos where one transmits the potentiometer readings and one receives it where it is displayed on some LED 7 segment displays (via Bluetooth or radio)

Comment: How many POT. are you trying to read ? based on this you should select a proper micro-controller with a suitable number of ADC channels

Comment: @Bradman Given the number of unexperienced developers suddenly starting to lay huge amounts of [useless] iPhone/Android apps these last years, I wouldn't say the mobile side will be the hardest part.

Comment: @dim well probably a subjective opinion of me then. I don't even know where to start with Xcode. I just get confused with all the terminologies. I think Arduino would be easier for an electronics based user.

Comment: Questions need to be specific, if the question is "Where can I find a resource?" Then use google. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask please write specific questions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you have recognised, it will need an analogue to digital converter (ADC) to read the potentiometers, and a way to package up that information, and send it over Bluetooth, in a form your phone can use. That is a microcontroller.

Reaching your size of 2x2x1 cm, is extremely challenging as a starting point. You are likely to need to develop custom electronics. I recommend you use a ready built development system, get it all working, then shrink to your target size.

For a low power application, you are looking for Bluetooth 'Smart' aka Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE).

There are specific Bluetooth 'profiles' for analogue data. There is a lot of complexity to those profiles. So if you want to take advantage of those, it is probably better to use a development system which has some support for Bluetooth or BLE profiles.

One approach is a microcontroller with a Bluetooth Low Energy 'daughter board', for example [ST Micro's Bluetooth Nucleo expansion board](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/ecosystems/stm32-open-development-environment/stm32-nucleo-expansion-boards/stm32-ode-connect-hw/x-nucleo-idb04a1.html) which plugs onto their St Nucleo-64 development boards. Several of those have low-energy microcontrollers. ST run free workshops and provide teaching material which you could probably get for free.

Several microcontroller manufacturers integrate bluetooth with the microcontroller. To make products easy to prototype, several mount the parts on modules.

One development system I am familiar with is from Cypress Semiconductor. They have two types of module a PSoC 4 BLE and PRoC BLE, along with a [Development kit](http://www.cypress.com/documentation/development-kitsboards/cy8ckit-042-ble-bluetooth-low-energy-ble-pioneer-kit). Again they have free workshops and teaching material. Cypress' workshops show a **demo mobile phone application** which communicates analogue data, using their BLE module, to a mobile phone. ST may also have a demo mobile phone app, I can't remember if they do.

You can probably get a Bluetooth Low Energy module, which has a UART (serial) interface, but I haven't checked. Most microcontrollers have a UART and Analogue to digital converters. You will also need to understand how its 'Low Energy' features work. You will have to decide how to get the data across to the phone, and write the mobile app.

For such a low speed application, toy might also consider WiFi. Their are many WiFi modules, but the cheapest I am aware of is Espressif's ESP8266. AGain, you will need to write the phone app.